# Achieving a global force logout using Okhttp's authenticator (along with RetroFit , RxJava and Dagger2)

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, retrofit2, okhttp

**The Task**

I have a situation in which if a refresh token request comes back with a 401, I would force a logout by clearing the user from the room and from memory. I would want to achieve this from inside of the Authenticator OR the Interceptor so I don't have to check for 401 as a response to each call.

**The Authenticator**

```
public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {
//        if (responseCount(response) >= 3) {
//            return null;
//        }
//
        UserCredentials userCredentials = new
                UserCredentials().
                CreateRefreshTokenRequest("refresh_token",
                        requestHeaders.getAccessToken().getRefreshToken(),
                        oAuthClient.getClientId(),
                        oAuthClient.getClientSecret());
        Request.Builder builder = response.request().newBuilder();

        if (accountsServicesHolder.getAccountsServices() == null)
            return null;

        //this HAS TO BE a Synchronous process. The usual RXjava shenanigans can't be applied here.
        try {
           //Synchronous call to get new token
            AccessToken accessToken = accountsServicesHolder.
                    getAccountsServices().
                    refreshToken(userCredentials.toMap()).
                    blockingGet();


            //persist the token in the db
            //userDao.save()

            //persist the token in memory

            //send an updated version to the backend
            builder.header("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken.getAccessToken());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            if (ex instanceof HttpException) { 
                return builder.
                        url(linksProvider.getProductionUrl().concat(logoutEndpoint)).
                        build(); //Redirecting this authenticator to a logout ws so that we do not get a 401 . Something goes wrong here 
            }
        }

        return builder.build();
    }
```

As you can see, if we do not get a token on basic of the refresh token, I am cunningly inserting a new URL into the builder. This is so that I do not get a 401 being bubbled up to where I made the initial call. I do not want a user to get a "401 You have not authorized" message rather I would display a toast saying "Session Expired"

**The Request Interceptor**

```
@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request original = chain.request();
    Request.Builder builder = original.newBuilder().
            header("Authorization", "Bearer " + requestHeaders.getAccessToken().getAccessToken()).
            header("Accept-Language", requestHeaders.getLanguage()).
            method(original.method(), original.body());
    Request newRequest = builder.build();

    Response response = chain.proceed(newRequest);

    if (response.code() == 200
            && response.request().url().toString().contains("logout")) {

        forceUserOut();
    }
    return response;
}
```

The forceUserOut method Broadcasts to the system that a logout has happened.
Since we have protected against a 401 now no errors would be displayed to the user.

**The Problem**

Okay, now we come to the problem. The place where I thought I was being cunned is perhaps not so smart after all. The authenticator runs an extra time after the logout API is called which runs after a thing that is supposed to happen afterward twice.

As far as I understand, the authenticator should have just executed the logout service and the interceptor should have started doing its job then.

The authenticator, however, does the following

1) Tries to get the new access token

2) Fails and calls the logout API (invokes the Interceptor and broadcasts the logout)

3) Fails and calls the logout API (invokes the interceptor and broadcasts the logout)

4) End

I know I might be breaking something inside the OkHttps authentication mechanism, but what other methods could I use in order to achieve a forced logout in a way I do not have to write a 401 check on all the APIs?

Extremely apologetic for the long question.

Comment: Have you find solution?

Comment: No lunaVulpo . I did circumvent this problem through some other mechanism that I can't quite remember now :( . Yes wait I remember . I had a global Error Handler class . So I just handled the 401 case in that single class.